# jQuery post method in admin menu

Tags: jquery, admin-menu

I'm trying to use this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#button").click(function(){
        jQuery.post("post_file.php")
    });
});
```

on this: 
    myaddress.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=pluginname/pluginfile.php_pluginfunction 
but what happens is that it opens this: 
    myaddress.com/wp-admin/admin.php?variables

How can I make it stay in plugin's function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'm just too tired. This helped:

```
<input type = "hidden" name = "page" value = "pluginname/pluginfile.php_pluginfunction " />
```